# BigQuery - Discrepancy in number of crashes

Tags: google-bigquery, crashlytics

I tried querying the number of crashes each day using the script provided on firebase's website:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) AS number_of_crashes,
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F", event_timestamp, "Singapore") AS date_of_crashes
FROM
 `projectId.firebase_crashlytics.package_name_ANDROID`
GROUP BY
  date_of_crashes
ORDER BY
  date_of_crashes DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

However, I see a discrepancy between the number of crashes from the query and the Crashlytics dashboard.

Below is the output I get using bigquery:

```
Row    number_of_crashes    date_of_crashes
1      559                  2020-02-05 
2      316                  2020-02-04
3      3                    2020-02-03
4      5                    2020-02-02
5      1                    2020-02-01
```

What I see from Crashlytics dashboard:

```
Row    number_of_crashes    date_of_crashes
1      948                  2020-02-05 
2      872                  2020-02-04
3      859                  2020-02-03
4      1024                 2020-02-02
5      977                  2020-02-01
```

May I know how can I resolve such issues?

Thanks!